# Получить элемент объекта React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Получаю объект с сервера и записываю его в состояние, но когда выбираю значение его элемента - Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Объект выглядит вот так:

```
[{userId: 1, id: 1, title: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit", body: "quia et suscipit↵suscipit recusandae consequuntur …strum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"},{userId: 1, id: 2, title: "qui est esse", body: "est rerum tempore vitae↵sequi sint nihil reprehend…aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"}]
```

Код самого компонента:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      messages:""
    }
    this.getMessage = this.getMessage.bind(this);
  }

   async getMessage(){
    const fetchMess = await fetch('https://json.code.com/post');
    const data = await fetchMess.json(); 
    this.setState({
      messages: data
    })

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('load', this.getMessage);

  }


  render(){
    console.log(this.state.messages[0].id);
    return(
     <div className="container">
        <AppReady />
        <Form />
        <Messages message={this.state.messages[0]}/>
     </div>
    );
  }

}
```

В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Не по теме. Компонент называется `Messages`, а передается одно сообщение. ват? семантика нарушена. Вы уверены что тут `const data = await fetchMess.json();` получаете массив?

Comment: Поправил тему.  const data получает массив - консолил. Но вот элемент почему то не выводит. Сообщение хотя бы одно пока пытаюсь отправить.

Comment: Подозреваю что проблема вся в `async` и `await` и в том что изначально `messages: ""` что есть не правильно. Вы пишете что это строка, а потом у Вас чудным обращом получается массив. Ват? где тут логика? сделайте пустой массив тогда. Попробуйте сделать без `async` и `await`.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась после того, как принял объект в глобальную переменную, а не в состояние.